# Validar query igualado por el Mes de 2 fechas

Tags: sql, sql-server

Como puedo hacer que un query me traiga resultados que por ejemplo la FechaPago sea igual al mismo mes de una variable

Me explico

Tengo este query

```
Declare @FechaReporte DATETIME
SET @FechaReporte = ‘2022-05-31’

Select 
NumCredito,
Nombre,
FechaPago
From Creditos
```

Ese query me trae una lista de créditos, lo que quiero es que me traiga únicamente los que en la FechaPago, se hayan pagado el mismo Mes de la variable, como la variable está en Mayo, todos los créditos que se hayan pagado en Mayo

Estaba intentando usar Month pero no lo he conseguido

Answer (score 2, accepted):

¿Cómo haz estado usando el `MONTH()`? Lo he probado y funciona bien .

1. Creo la tabla de prueba de créditos.

```sql
create table creditos (numcredito int, nombre varchar(22), fechapago date)

insert into creditos values(10, 'luis', '2022-05-06')
insert into creditos values(12, 'luis2', '2022-06-06')
insert into creditos values(32, 'luis3', '2022-07-06')
insert into creditos values(41, 'luis4', '2022-05-21')
insert into creditos values(12, 'luis5', '2022-06-12')
```

| numcredito | nombre | fechapago |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | luis | 2022-05-06 |
| 12 | luis2 | 2022-06-06 |
| 32 | luis3 | 2022-07-06 |
| 41 | luis4 | 2022-05-21 |
| 12 | luis5 | 2022-06-12 |

2. Ejecuta esta instrucción tal cual:

```sql
declare @fechareporte datetime 
set @fechareporte = '2022-05-31' 

select * 
from creditos
where month(fechapago) = month(@fechareporte)
```

El output debería ser:

| numcredito | nombre | fechapago |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | luis | 2022-05-06 |
| 41 | luis4 | 2022-05-21 |

> Lo probé en este [DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6a8f3518e596877a8f416f554ef8f667)